# JPA - NamedQuery of name: User.checkCredentials not found

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6

I'm trying to do a credentials check of the user using JPA.
Every time I run the code, I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name:
> User.checkCredentials not found.

I've done lots of tries but I can't find how to figured out what's causing the error.

(I've created the database on MySQL and I've called it "gamified_marketing")

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome back to the Gamified Marketing application</h1>
    <form action="CheckLogin" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="usr" required> <br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" required> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
        <p th:text=" ${errorMsg}"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CheckLogin**

```
@WebServlet("/CheckLogin")
public class CheckLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    @EJB(name = "it.polimi.db2.services/UserService")
    private UserService usrService;
    
    public CheckLogin() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String usr = null;
        String pwd = null;
        
        try {
            usr = request.getParameter("usr");
            pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
            if (usr == null || pwd == null || usr.isEmpty() || pwd.isEmpty()) {
                throw new Exception("Missing or empty credential value");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Missing credential value");
            return;
        }
        
        User user;
        try {
            user = usrService.checkCredentials(usr, pwd);
        } catch (CredentialsException | NonUniqueResultException e) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Could not check credentials");
            return;
        }
```

**UserService**

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "GamifiedMarketingApplicationEJB")
    private EntityManager em;

    public UserService() {}

    public User checkCredentials(String usr, String pwd) throws CredentialsException, NonUniqueResultException {
        List<User> uList = null;
        
        try {
            uList = em.createNamedQuery("User.checkCredentials", User.class).setParameter(1, usr).setParameter(2, pwd).getResultList();
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new CredentialsException("Could not verify credentals");
        }
        
        if (uList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else if (uList.size() == 1)
            return uList.get(0);
        throw new NonUniqueResultException("More than one user registered with same credentials");
    }
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Userr", schema = "gamified_marketing")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.checkCredentials", query = "SELECT r FROM User r  WHERE r.username = ?1 and r.password = ?2")

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String username;
    
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String lastLogin;
    ...
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="GamifiedMarketingApplicationEJB"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>GamifiedMarketing</jta-data-source>
        <class>it.polimi.db2.entities.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: After adding the named query, have you done a "clean and build" of the project?

Comment: @perissf Yes I've done it, but nothing happened